# Comparing two strings through a selector: unexpected result

Tags: objective-c, automatic-ref-counting, selector

I am doing an exercise to learn how to use selectors in Objective-C.
In this code I am trying to compare two strings:

```
int main (int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    @autoreleasepool
    {
        SEL selector= @selector(caseInsensitiveCompare:);
        NSString* str1=@"hello";
        NSString* str2=@"hello";
        id result=[str1 performSelector: selector withObject: str2];
        NSLog(@"%d",[result boolValue]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

But it prints zero.Why?

Edit:
And if I change str2 to @"hell" I get an EXC_BAD_ACCESS.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The documentation for [`performSelector:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSObject_Protocol/Reference/NSObject.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/NSObject/performSelector%3a) states *"For methods that return anything other than an object, use NSInvocation".* Since `caseInsensitiveCompare:` returns an `NSInteger` instead of an object you will need to create an [`NSInvocation`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsinvocation_Class/Reference/Reference.html), which is more involved.

```
NSInteger returnVal;
SEL selector= @selector(caseInsensitiveCompare:);
NSString* str1=@"hello";
NSString* str2=@"hello";

NSMethodSignature *sig = [NSString instanceMethodSignatureForSelector:selector];
NSInvocation *invocation = [NSInvocation invocationWithMethodSignature:sig];
[invocation setTarget:str1];
[invocation setSelector:selector];
[invocation setArgument:&str2 atIndex:2]; //Index 0 and 1 are for self and _cmd
[invocation invoke];//Call the selector
[invocation getReturnValue:&returnVal];

NSLog(@"%ld", returnVal);
```

Comment: Nice answer.Just one question: is normal that it may return 18446744073709551615 (comparing @"hello" and @"hell") ?

Comment: No that is not normal, how did you get that number? You copy and pasted my code and just changed one to `hell`? The only values I am getting are `1`,`0`, and `-1`.

Comment: The same code, but just it was the wrong format: I did write %lu instead of %d (to fix a xcode warning).Changed it to %ld and it works.Thanks.

Comment: @RamyAlZuhouri `%ld` is [correct](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/formatSpecifiers.html), `%lu` causes an underflow when the number is negative which results in that big number.

Answer (score 1):

try

```
NSString* str1=@"hello";
NSString* str2=@"hello";

if ([str1 caseInsensitiveCompare:str2] == NSOrderedSame)
            NSLog(@"%@==%@",str1,str2);
else
            NSLog(@"%@!=%@",str1,str2);
```

Comment: This should be the correct answer, as it uses the "compare" flow (NSOrderedSame, NSOrderedAscending, NSOrderedDescending)