# Dynamically calling a method with parameters

Tags: objective-c, ios

I know it's possible to call a method by its name like this:

```
 NSString *string =@"methodName";
[self performSelector:NSSelectorFromString(string)];
```

And that it will execute the method below:

```
-(void)methodName
   {
              // todo:.....
   }
```

I'm wondering how to call a method which has parameters like this:

```
-(void)methodName:(NSString *)_name :withValue (NSString *) value
     {
              // todo:.....
     }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use -performSelector:withObject:

```
NSDictionary *dic = @{@"name":@"stringName",@"value":@"12"};

NSString *string =@"methodName:";
[self performSelector:NSSelectorFromString(string) withObject:dic];
```

And in -methodName:

```
-(void) methodName:(id)obj
{
    NSDictionary *dic = (NSDictionary *)obj;
    [self methodName:dic[@"name"] withValue:dic[@"value"]];
}
```

Comment: i cant directly pass the arguments to the method?

Comment: Yes, it is impossible by performSelector, as I know. 
You can refer to [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8439052/ios-how-to-implement-a-performselector-with-multiple-arguments-and-with-afterd) for some detail. Maybe you could try dispatch if you really want multiple parameters.

Comment: i go with your answer and it worked for me and better to have a dictionary while passing the args with the help of key while coding dynamically thanks onevcat

Answer (score 2):

I don't know the exact syntax off the top of my head, but you can do this with [NSInvocation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSInvocation_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

Comment: For who needs it an example here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11477951/comparing-two-strings-through-a-selector-unexpected-result , it also explains how to take the return value.

Answer (score 0):

Well I dont know what exactly is needed but from my understanding , it is something like :

```
NSArray *fruits = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Apple", @"Mango", nil]; 
NSArray *drinks = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Drink1", @"Drink2",nil];
[self serveOrdersWith:fruits andDrinks:drinks];
```

Somewhere in the class , the method will be called with the argument array fruits i.e.

```
-(NSArray*)serveOrdersWith :(NSArray*)array1 andDrinks:(NSArray*)array2{
     //Your code here but I will finish with this only
    NSArray *orderArray;
    [orderArray addObject:array1];
    [orderArray addObject:array2];
    return orderArray;
}
```